# How to use functions/methods in SWITCH CASE statement in Java

Tags: java

I have 3 types of array:
`ControlType`
`ControlName`
`ControlValue`

When the control type is "ClickButton", I have to pass the corresponding ControlName and ControlValue.

Code:

```
public class StringSwitchDemo extends StringSwitchDemoHelper
{
    public static int getMonthNumber(String ControlType) {
        int ControlValue = 0;
        int ControlName  = 0;

        if (ControlType == null) {
            return ControlValue;
        }

        switch (ControlType.toString()) {
            case ClickButton:
                return ControlType(ControlValue, ControlName);
                break;
        }

        return ControlValue;
    }

    private static int ControlType(String controlValue, String controlName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need (and can't put) a `break` directly after a `return`, because it is unreachable. The `break` will never be hit, because the method has returned.

Comment: Is `ClickButton` a compile-time constant string?

Comment: @khelwood New Users seems only to ask questions and not to reply!!!!

Comment: Yes..ClickButton is a string...Its a generic method to click a button a web page

Comment: You only need to write "return" not the break statement . Its compile time error. Now are you asking if your code is right or not? Another thing why are you doing toString() on array? I dont think that is a good idea , it is only going to give you string representation of array.

Comment: @GopinathRavi `ClickButton` is either a String or a method -- it can't be both!

Comment: I don't see a question in your post. Nor any description of the errors / unexpected results.

Comment: if ClickButton is  a string then you have to put it in " " quotes

Comment: How to pass the corresponding 'ControlName' and 'ControlValue' when the 'ControlType' is 'ClickButton'?

Comment: The convention in Java is for variables to start with a lower case letter: `controlType` not `ControlType`. Seems trivial, but experienced Java programmers see `ControlType` and assume it's a class name. Good IDEs will warn you about this. I suggest fixing it in your question.

Comment: Is your code compiling? I think you need more time to learn Java. Why are you using switch rather than if? What happens if its not clickbutton event i.e. what should be the control value be? You have return type as int and you are returning control value?

Comment: Switch can not be applied to a method and you can not pass function as parameter in Java world. Welcome to the world of OOP from functional programming.

Comment: It is a seperate method..Still do i need to put it in " " quotes? @java fan

Comment: ooo,no answer only discussions

Comment: @GopinathRavi If it is a method then it should have () after it.

Comment: @javafan no answer, since no question is present in the post.

Comment: @slim its true for this question

Comment: I simplified like below:

Answer (score 0):

You can only use constants (final variables) and literals in switch statements.

```
public static final String MY_CONST = "foo";

public static int getMonthNumber(String ControlType) {
    int ControlValue = 0;
    int ControlName  = 0;

    if (ControlType == null) {
        return ControlValue;
    }

    switch (ControlType) {
        case MY_CONST: // this will work
            break;
        case "ClickButton":
            return ControlType(ControlValue, ControlName);
    }

    return ControlValue;
}

private static int ControlType(int controlValue, int controlName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return 0;
}
```

Also, please read the [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) for Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
I simplified like below:

`import resources.StringSwitchDemoHelper;
/**
 * Description   : Functional Test Script
 * @author IBM
 */


public class StringSwitchDemo extends StringSwitchDemoHelper
{

    public static String getControlValue(String controlType) {

        String controlValue = null;
        String controlName  = null;

        if (controlType == null) {
            return controlValue;
        }

        switch (controlType) {
            case "Html.INPUT.text":
                return EnterText (controlName,controlValue);
        }
    return controlValue;

    }

public static String EnterText(String controlName, String value)
{
    TextGuiTestObject textObj = findList(controlName);
    if (textObj != null) {
    textObj.setText(value);
    } else {
    throw new ObjectNotFoundException();
    }
    return value;}
}`

Still it is not working!!
```